# Make :active take effect after following href

Tags: css

Consider a dropdown menu, which opens on mouse hover and closes when an item is clicked ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/mgoldenb/pen/NWadeLR)):

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    &:hover {
        .dropdown-items {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    &:active {
        .dropdown-items {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}

.dropdown-items {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
  Dropdown
  <div class="dropdown-items">
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once the user clicks on the link, the dropdown menu closes before the download has a chance to take place. How can I make the download take place and still have the dropdown menu close on click? I am looking for a solution without JavaScript.

Comment: What does the drop down closing... have to do with a download happening? it's always going to close before the download finishes.

Comment: @KevinB If I comment out the `&:active` ruleset, a download attempt takes place. For some reason, once `display:none` takes effect, nothing else does.

Comment: you'll just have to use something other than display:none.

Comment: @KevinB For example? And, are you sure it works?

Comment: I've tried everything I can think of including delays and animations and nothing is working reliably. Is there a good reason for why you don't want to use JavaScript?

Comment: What i can confirm, is that hiding it with :active prevents you from clicking it, as :active gets applied before you release the mouse. *not* hiding it will of course solve your problem, so you could not hide it, while still making it not visible. ;)

Comment: @KevinB I am really wondering, why is this a bad question?

Comment: It is not a bad question but it appears limiting yourself to CSS only is holding back a solution. There are well documented solutions with JavaScript on this site.